# Authenticating to ServiceStack with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, servicestack, restful-authentication

We are looking to build an Angular 2 SPA using ServiceStack. We are primarily looking for a getting started type of instructions/demos on handling authentication, uploading files, etc using Typescript if possible. Documentation seems to be extremely sparse on this at the moment. Any leads or help on this will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact it's using Angular shouldn't matter, but there are a number of [auth-enabled Live Demos](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#live-demos)  listed in the docs.

Comment: Thank you! I enjoy ServiceStack by the way. I appreciate you responding promptly to any questions on it.